# R shiny: multiple inputs in reactive{}

Tags: r, shiny

Hi I am pretty new to Shiny. I'm trying to create two interactive selectInputs for my user to show data in the table. Here is what my code looks like:
ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      selectInput("var", 
                  label = "Country",
                  choices = c("ALL",  "A2", "AE")),
      selectInput("plat", 
                  label = "Platform",
                  choices = c("ALL", "Android", "IPhonePlayer"))
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(

      tableOutput(
        "view"))
  )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df <- readRDS("data/df.rds")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

 datasetInput <- reactive({

    switch(input$var,
           "ALL" = df,
           "A2" = df %>% filter(country == "A2"),
           "AE" = df %>% filter(country == "AE"))


    switch(input$plat,
           "ALL" = df,
           "Android" = df %>% filter(platform == "Android"),
           "IPhonePlayer" = df %>% filter(platform == "IPhonePlayer"))



  })


   output$view <- renderTable({head(datasetInput())})

})
```

When I run the code, only the select on platform works properly, while for country, nothing happens when I make the selection. Any ideas on what stupid mistakes I'm making here? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try assign the result of the first `switch` to `df`. Right now, the two `switch` is not connected, and the `reactive` only returns the result of the second one.

```
df <- switch(input$var,
       "ALL" = df,
       "A2" = df %>% filter(country == "A2"),
       "AE" = df %>% filter(country == "AE"))
```

Comment: Can you be more detail? I tried to assign it as you suggested but still got the same result. I must have assigned in the wrong way. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not what you are asking for, but I think you can improve your code like this:

```
datasetInput <- reactive({
  df %>%
    filter(
      (input$var  == 'ALL' | country == input$var) &
      (input$plat == 'ALL' | country == input$plat)
    )
})
```

Comment: Thank you! This indeed save me some trouble.